# How to enable centering Marker on Map in IOS using React native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, compatibility, react-native-maps

I am using Map component from `react-native-maps`, and I display many markers in it, but whenever  click on a Marker on *Android* the marker clicked is centered automatically, while this behavior does not exist in *IOS*.

Is there a way to make markers get centered too in *IOS*, or at least disable it from *Android*.
I want to have the same behavior in both OSs.

Any help or idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either set

```
<MapView
moveOnMarkerPress={false}
...
/>
```

which would disable the android-behavior, or you could handle the MarkerPress on iOS and center the MapView on it, something like this:

```
 <MapView
    ...
    ref={ref => {
       this.map = ref;
    }}
    >
      {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          ...
          onSelect=(({coordinate}) =>  this.map.animateCamera({center: coordinate}, { duration: 2000 }))
        />
      ))}
    </MapView>
```